# Read only usernames in django admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using django and its built in admin site for the project I'm working on. (Python 3.4, django 1.7)

For the current project I'm working on I require usernames to be fixed after object creation. I have made a small test project, which literally contains one app, and that app only contains this admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self,request, obj=None):
            ro_fields = list(super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj))
            if obj is not None:
                    ro_fields.append('username')
            return ro_fields

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyAdmin)
```

As expected, the Username can be set in the Add page and is Read Only in the change page. However, I cannot save when on the change page, I receive the message "please correct the errors below" but no field is highlighted. Can anyone suggest a way to work round this problem?

EDIT: as a diferent option I attempted to replace the username with a widget that didn't allow input - no luck there either

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source HTML of the page with the error to see if there's one on a hidden field for some reason?

Comment: Hi, I'm also stuck with the same issue with `python 2.7 & django 1.7`. Did you find any cause/fix for it?

Comment: Yes, password and username MUST be returned for the save to succeed. Using the readonly fields that way stops them being sent back up. I made my own widget which presents it as read only, but also includes the values as a hidden input to the post request. I also added some processing logic so that if they have been changed despite being hidden, the original value is substituted back in